# html data-* and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need an interactive tooltip or something similar as shown in this [example](http://www.fiatprofessional.com/com/Models/fullback-pick-up).

There is a sign that when you rollover it, you will see the description and when you click on it you will see a custom div appears.

This is the code of one of those tooltips:

```
<div class="selettore-9" data-over="overDiv" style="position:absolute;margin-top:355px; margin-left:680px;z-index: 3;">
    <div class="selettore">+</div>
    <div class="selettore-text" data-infostyle-tab="tabTSA">TSA</div>
</div>    
<div data-info-tab="tabTSA" class="infoTab">
    <div class="tabInfoContent">
        <div class="chiudiInfo" data-close-tab="tabTSA">+</div>
        <img class="tabInfoContentImage image-center" src="/com/CMSEN/PublishingImages/imagesUpload/Modelli/Fullback/img/style_safety/03_tsa_style_safety.png">
        <div class="tabInfoContentTitle text-center">TSA</div>
        <div class="tabInfoContentText text-center">
            The Trailer Stability Assist system guarantees a perfect stability even in case of towing: if the vehicle swerves, 
            the TSA automatically modulates the engine's power and forces the car to brake, restoring the vehicle's towing stability.
        </div>
        <img class="tabInfoContentDetailImage image-center" src="/com/CMSEN/PublishingImages/imagesUpload/Modelli/Fullback/img/style_safety/04_tsa_infografica.png">
    </div>
</div>

dataOver = $('.fullStyle .backImage').find('[data-over="overDiv"]');
$(dataOver).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".selettore-text").switchClass('selettore-text', 'selettore-text-over', 200, 'easeInQuad');
});
$(dataOver).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".selettore-text-over").switchClass('selettore-text-over', 'selettore-text', 200, 'easeInQuad');
});
```

I tried to use `data_*`, but I failed to linked it as I'm new in javascript.

Comment: So where is the rest of the code? What uses `data-over`?

Comment: please put the code you tried.

Comment: Now that you added the example link of some other site, it takes more than just adding an attribute to an element, they have other code running that reads the attributes.

Comment: @epascarello not looking for the same code or technique but the same result as well

Comment: So is this code working, or not, and if not in what way is it not? I don't see any code handling a click--am I missing something?

Comment: @torazaburo, this is a `give me the code` type-question, Which action must be taken?